# Rope tension definition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics, string

What is the exact definition of the tension of a rope?

Here http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/modules/chapter08.pdf the following definition is given

> The tension   $T(x)$ in a rope at a distance $x$ from one end of the rope is the magnitude of the action -reaction pair of forces acting at the point  $x$.

But I think that this is valid only in the case that the tension is the same, throughout all the rope. Is that definition still valid in that case?

Comment: The definition is valid for all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition given by mit is perfectly correct. I don't see any problem with it.